# NOR and NAND operator tautology

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, binary-operations

I am having trouble with a problem in the book I studied about logic that use the NOR operator (also known as Peirce's arrow) and the NAND operator.

The discrete math book said this is tautology $A↓(A↓A) \equiv T$.
We know that $(A↓A) \equiv \mathord\sim A$ where $ ↓$ is the NOR symbol.

so  $A↓(A↓A) \equiv A↓ \mathord\sim A \equiv \mathord\sim(A \lor \mathord\sim A) \equiv F$
but the book said  that since we know  $(A↓A) \equiv \mathord\sim A \equiv (A|A) $ where | is NAND symbol

$A↓(A↓A) \equiv A| \mathord\sim A \equiv \mathord\sim (A \land \mathord\sim A) \equiv\mathord\sim F \equiv T$ so it is a tautology.

So is it a tautology or not?

Comment: Please explain this step: $A↓(A↓A) \equiv A| \sim A$

Comment: @Deepak $(A↓A) \equiv \sim A \equiv (A|A)$ so since $(A↓A) \equiv \sim A$ we can change  $A↓(A↓A) \equiv A↓ \sim A $ and since $(A↓A) \equiv (A|A)$ we can change $A↓ \sim A $ to $A| \sim A$

Comment: A NAND A = A & A NOR A = A work precisely because both operands are the same. This doesn't hold when you're working with A and NOT(A). So that step "we can change..." is wrong.

Comment: I meant that A NAND A = NOT(A) & A NOR A = NOT (A) work because the operands are both A (identical). The relations don't work in the other case.

Comment: @Deepak Ok so the answer should be not a tautology?

Comment: You can get proper spacing around `\sim` when using it as a unary rather than binary operator by using `\mathord{\sim}` instead: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129958.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement is a tautology if it is true under every possible interpretations of the literals that form it.  Here is the truth table for $\downarrow$.

[image]

So if $A$ is true, then $$A\downarrow(A\downarrow A) \equiv T\downarrow(T\downarrow T)\equiv T\downarrow F\equiv F$$ and if $A$ is false then $$A\downarrow(A\downarrow A) \equiv F\downarrow(F\downarrow F)\equiv F\downarrow T\equiv F$$

So, not only is $A\downarrow(A\downarrow A)$ not a tautology, it is a contradiction.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer! Help me clear up my confusion!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be many parts to what you're asking so I'll just break down your question:

"$A↓(A↓A) \equiv T$"

is wrong.

Instead it should be

$A↓(A↓A) \equiv F$

which is an always-false statement. This is the opposite of a tautology and is known as a contradiction.

"we know that $(A↓A) \equiv \sim A$ where $ ↓$ is NOR symbol."

Correct.

"so  $A↓(A↓A) \equiv A↓ \sim A \equiv \sim(A \lor \sim A) \equiv F$"

All correct.

"but the book said  that since we know  $(A↓A) \equiv \sim A \equiv (A|A) $ where | is NAND symbol"

This is correct and holds when both operands are identical.

"$A↓(A↓A) \equiv A| \sim A...$"

Wrong. It is unclear how you made that leap.

"$...\equiv \sim (A \land \sim A) \equiv\sim F \equiv T$"

The rest of this chain of reasoning (after the wrong step) is correct but obviously the conclusion is wrong because of that earlier mistake.

I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Started my answer, broke for dinner and got beaten to the punch. :)